# DOM HTML & JS scrape from JS part

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, preg-match-all, simple-html-dom

I want to scrape links from one page to another with HTML DOM pharser.

The other webpage has this code :

```
$('#vidabc-fast-watch-button').click(function() {
  $('#fast-watch-frame').attr('src','http://vidabc.com/embed-8fyiakzp0ob8.html');
});                     
$('#kingvid-fast-watch-button').click(function() {

  $('#vidwatch-fast-watch-button').click(function() {
    $('#fast-watch-frame').attr('src','');
  });
  $('#estream-fast-watch-button').click(function() {
    $('#fast-watch-frame').attr('src','http://estream.to/embed-2605th4kkypl.html');
  });
  $('#openload-fast-watch-button').click(function() {
    $('#fast-watch-frame').attr('src','http://openload.co/embed/YsaOx8K5Bk0/');
  });
```

I want to scrape information to another PHP page and `preg_match` the url.
But couldn't find links inside JS code.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You could match the URLs inside the script by looking at the text content of the `script` tag, and launch a `preg_match_all` on it:

```
$scr = $doc->getElementsByTagName('script')[0]->textContent;
preg_match_all("/http:[\w#\[\]@!$&()*+,;=%:\/.?~-]*/", $scr, $urls);

print_r($urls[0]);
```

For the given example this would output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://vidabc.com/embed-8fyiakzp0ob8.html
    [1] => http://estream.to/embed-2605th4kkypl.html
    [2] => http://openload.co/embed/YsaOx8K5Bk0/
)
```

See it run on [`eval.in`](https://eval.in/751728)